# Неужели никак нельзя раскрасить статусбар на пре-лоллипоп?

Tags: android

Красить статусбар можно только начиная с API 21. Почему? Мне кажется, что-то можно сделать, только вот никто не хочет. Наблюдал, что если поставить `Fullscreen` в стиль приложения и открыть шторку, то на время вылезает полупрозрачный статусбар серого цвета.

**100%** можно сделать, чтобы этот эффект наблюдался постоянно, должен быть какой-то хак. Далее заменить это цвет, пороясь в теме. Узнать его высоту и сделать `marginTop` в разметке.

Правильно мыслю? Или просто время зря потрачу?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Статус бар - элемент UI операционной системы. Устройства с ОС ниже 5.0 не имеют разрешение на изменение цвета статус бара.

Но на API >= 19 можно цвет фона статус бара сделать прозрачным, тогда статус бар будет того же цвета, что и фон в приложении.
Чтобы сделать это, в файл styles.xml в value-v19 надо написать:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

        <style name="AppTheme" parent="MaterialDrawerTheme.Light">
                <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
                <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
                <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
                .....
        </style>
</resources>
```